# Why won't Jarrik the Crusher appear in Mammoth Keep?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

I'm doing the quest, "The Crusher's End" were you kill the Bandit leader, Jarrik the Crusher. But in the keep it is only other bandits there, not him. I have searched the entire keep, killed everyone but he is not there. The arrow just points to the center of the main room. How do I fix it?

Comment: I never found a solution for this problem, but I experienced the exact same thing. I would always go, kill everyone I found and the arrow would point to the center of the room.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to spawn him manually, in the console enter `prid xx11d62b` (`xx` being whatever the id for the Falskaar mod is) then `enable`, then `moveto player`
and it should spawn him. (I'm not sure if you even need to enable but it's better to do so. I also used `resurrect` just to be safe.)

For whatever reason, he doesn't seem to spawn properly, and the arrow just points to the rooms centre, but you can spawn him yourself and continue things just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This mod/DLC is not without flaws. After saying this, same thing happened to me.

Investigate bodies in the main chamber. If you killed them all, then "The Crusher's" body should be there. I have played this mod 4 times now. His body should always be in the main chamber. HTH

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to spawn him manually, in the console enter prid xx11d62b (xx being whatever the id for the Falskaar mod is) then enable, then moveto player and it should spawn him. (I'm not sure if you even need to enable but it's better to do so. I also used resurrect just to be safe.)

- where do I find the mod id?